# Copy row data from Workbook A to the end of the row on Workbook B if the Cell in Workbook A Column A matches a cell in Workbook B Column C

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks I need to move data around in.  If a cell in workbook A column A has the same data in it as workbook B column C then I need to copy columns B, C, D, E to the end of the row in workbook B.  How can I go about doing this.

Workbook A

```
----------------------------------------------
A        |      B       |      C       |     D     |   E    |
12             11             55             66        77
```

Workbook B

```
------------------------------------------------------------
A        |      B       |      C       |     D     |   E    |
Work           book           12            copy data from workbook A to end of this row
```

Comment: You would break down the steps and then google each step.  There are many answers to this out there.

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried.  SO can build upon your code, and help with the coding mistakes, but is not intended to be code-for-you.  This is a collaborative site.

Comment: I have tried this       =IF($C2=Sheet1!$A1:$A3600, VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1, Sheet1!$A1:$E1, 2),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little processor intensive, but figured it out.

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,Sheet2!$A:$A)))>0,LOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet2!$B:$B),"")